# How to aggregate JPA entities in seperate jars into a single persistence unit?

Tags: java, jpa

In my application right now I have one project which contains all the JPA entities. I would like to modularize my application along feature lines:

- Feature1.jar - has all JPA entities for feature 1, business logic, ui logic ... etc
- Feature2.jar - has all JPA entities for feature 2, business logic, ... etc

How can JPA 2.0 be configured to place the JPA entities in Feature1.jar and Feature2.jar into the same persistence unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tag `<jar-file>` in persistence unit

```
<jar-file>Feature1.jar</jar>
<jar-file>Feature2.jar</jar>
```

ear should look like

```
.ear 
+- /lib 
|  +- persistence.jar
|     +- /META-INF 
|        +- persistence.xml 
+- .war file
+- Feature1.jar
+- Feature2.jar
```